# ¿Por que mi proyecto no corre en el emulador de Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

Eh descargado eclipse y creado un proyecto pero al  momento de correrlo dentro del emulador me manda los siguientes errores y me dice que mi proyecto contiene errores aun cuando no tiene ninguno.

> [2018-04-06 12:50:14 - Dex Loader] Failed to load C:\Users\josealexis\android-sdks\build-tools\27.0.3\lib\dx.jar
>   [2018-04-06 12:50:14 - MisAplicaciones1] Unknown error: Unable to build: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder!

Comment: Estás tratando de hacer una aplicación de android?

Comment: Si, estoy creando una aplicación de android en eclipse

Comment: Ya le agregué la etiqueta. Podrías agregar a la pregunta la ubicación de tu android SDK? La configuración de las variables de sistema PATH, Java_HOME, y similares que tengan que ver con el desarrollo de aplicaciones de android?

Comment: que version de eclipse utilizas , hay variedad de eclipse para desarrollo movil,